# How to display a JSON Object with ListView

Tags: javascript, winjs

I am trying to display a json object with listView using the code below and have no error message but it doesn't works.

```
return WinJS.xhr({
    url: "http://rest-api.wasamundi.com/search/?q=" + userInput
}).then(function (response) {
    try {
        var result = response.responseText;
        var obj = eval("(" + result + ")");

    }
    catch (e) {

    }

    //code pour objet recuperer du web
    var dataArray = result;
    //create object for data obtained from the web
    var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataArray);

    var publicMembers =
        {
            itemList: dataList
        };
    WinJS.Namespace.define("DataResult", publicMembers);
```

Comment: Have you confirmed you are getting JSON data back from your request?

Comment: yes i get the json data correctly with var result = response.responseText;